# Two models with login

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing an app that at this moment has only one model with login, called reader.

But in the future, there will be another model called company that will require login as well.

So I'm thinking what's the best way to develop it.

I thought that having a model called login with:

1. email
2. password
3. models reader
4. company inherit from it

but I have no idea if it's the best way to do it.

**I'm not using any gem like Devise.**

I'm developing my own login system.

So, what do you recommend?

Whats the best way?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I would *not* recommend rolling your own login system, that's for sure.

Comment: So, what do you recommend Makoto? I can use Devise, but I can't find a way to solve my problem.

Comment: I'm fairly confident that you can leverage Devise to create more than one model that's secured by it.  Have a read of their documentation to see where you'd get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

When the different users that use the application have completely different experience what I use is [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

in your **Gemfile**

`gem "devise"`

then you install

`rails generate devise:install`

then you create your models

`rails generate devise user`
`rails generate devise manager`

Here is the key in your routs you can do something like this

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {
    registrations: 'users/registrations',
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    passwords: 'users/passwords',
    confirmations: 'users/confirmations'
  }

  authenticate :user do
    namespace :users do
      ...
      root :to => 'dashboards#index'
     end
   end

  devise_for :managers, :controllers => {
    registrations: 'managers/registrations',
    sessions: 'managers/sessions"'
    passwords: 'managers/passwords',
    confirmations: 'managers/confirmations'
  }

  authenticate :manager do
    namespace :managers do
      ...
      root :to => 'dashboards#index'
     end
   end
```